# Golang create a slice of maps

Tags: dictionary, go, hashmap, slice, key-value

I was trying to create a slice of maps the following way.

```
keyvalue := make(map[string]interface{})
keyvalueslice := make([]keyvalue, 1, 1)
```

I was trying to create it just like the way string slice is created, however I am getting an error saying `keyvalue is not a type.` I am creating this slice to append data to `keyvalueslice` variable later.

Can someone explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`keyvalue` is a **variable** not a **type**, you can't create a slice of variables. If you want to define custom type you can do this like

```
type keyvalue map[string]interface{}
```

then you can create a slice of `keyvalue`s:

```
keyvalueslice := make([]keyvalue, 1, 1)
```

Example on [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8MraIphEmlC)

Or you can do this without defining custom type:

```
keyvalueslice := make([]map[string]interface{}, 1, 1)
```